# ARtoolkit install

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I install the ARtoolkit library? (Ubuntu 10.04, ROS electric)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32334/artoolkit-install/) by [Janina](https://answers.ros.org/users/1871/janina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may install [ccny_vision](http://ros.org/wiki/ccny_vision), which will have artoolkit and a ros package called ar_pose that will publish detected markers.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, can somebody help me on installing artoolkit on Ubuntu 12.04.3 (64 bit) and hydro? I tried ar_pose and I installed artoolkit for gstream. But if I compile artoolkit with gstream I can not use ar_pose. I tried to install ccny_vision too, but the server of ccny_vision is not available.

---

Originally posted by [anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/6751/anton/) with karma: 41 on 2013-09-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1